# Kill a person when he enters a certain location

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I want the player targeted by this target selector to be killed, but for some reason it doesn't work. I'm sure the repeating command block is executing correctly, what could be wrong?

```
execute as @a[x=291,y=69,z=-209,dx=10,dz=10] run kill @s
```

Comment: Are you trying to kill people just in the Y level 69, or not? When you specify `dx` and `dz`, the system automatically adds `dy` and it defaults to 0.

Comment: @Penguin Nope, if you specify even just one of `dx`, `dy`, and `dz`, the rest are automatically added and default to 0, meaning one block wide/tall/long.

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 oh, i bet ur right thats likely their issue then

Comment: I've fixed the problem myself I had the wrong coordinates, and dy doesn't change anything.

Comment: Would it work to do `kill @a[selector...]` instead? I'm not sure if `execute` is necessary here/

Answer (score -1):

Use `kill @p`

Explanation:

@s kills the entity that is executing the command, which is the command block and the entity you're trying to target is not the command block

Meanwhile,
@p targets the nearest player

And if you want to target y pos throughout the world, set dy to 255